# How can I convert my document similar to this one

Tags: fonts, margins, fontfamily

[image]

\
Few days ago, I found these note, and I got impressed with the style in which these notes are written. I also wanted to make my (math) notes like this.

But I am a beginner, in latex (overleaf), so I had not much knowledge about how can I convert my document like this. However, I used this site for few days and somehow I understood, how can I write section at center, page numbering on the top etc.

My codes in preamble are :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,english]{article}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{tgtermes}
%\usepakage{times}
\usepackage[paperheight=600pt,paperwidth=515pt ,bottom=-7mm,right=22.4mm]{geometry}
\setlength{\headsep}{5mm}
%\setlength{\hoffset}{0pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1pt}
%\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0mm}
%\setlength{\marginparsep}{0mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{1pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{1.6mm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-8mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{5mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{370pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{530pt}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\bfseries}{}{1em}{}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
%\usepackage{sectsty}
%\allsectionsfont{\centering}
%\titlelabel{\thetitle . \enspace}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\centering}{\arabic{section}.}{1em}{}
%\sectionfont{\centering}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{calc}
%\usepackage{showframe}
%\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
%\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
```

**Question**:
But the only thing I have stuck and after alot of searching I can't figure out is, what is the name of these font styles and how can I load these fonts in my **entire** document?

[image]

Moreover, I tried to set the similar margins too. But I couldn't figure out margins just by looking at pdf.\
Is it possible to figure out similar margins from pdf?.If yes, then how?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

**Edit**:
Here I am talking about, the font style of whole document. Although at first sight the fonts in this pdf seems default to me. But when I compared it with my written pdf (in default fonts), that is

[image]

I found, the fonts in the document are not default.

**Edit.2**
The minimal working example is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,english]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[paperheight=600pt,paperwidth=515pt ,bottom=-7mm,right=22.4mm]{geometry}
\setlength{\headsep}{5mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{1pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{1.6mm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-8mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{5mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{370pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{530pt}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\centering\scshape}{\arabic{section}.}{1em}{}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\title{My doc}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

**Edit.3**
With help and guidance of Mirco, I slighty modify Mirco code and got what actually I wanted.
Moreover, now I know the dimension of the pdf that is 11.33 × 14.67 in (portrait). How can I issue this in the document?

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=3.75cm, top=1.74cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=3.74cm,right=3.74cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\hyphenation{pre-image} % avoid "preim-age"

\usepackage{cleveref} % for "clever" cross-references
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{REAL ANALYSIS}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%\usepackage{amsthm} % is loaded automatically by 'amsart' class
\theoremstyle{theorem} % italic lettering
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] 
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition} % all theorem-like environments to share the same counter

\theoremstyle{definition} % upright lettering
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark} % 'remark' env.: not numbered

\usepackage[scr=euler]{mathalpha} % for "Euler script"

\usepackage{enumitem} % for \newlist and \setlist macros
\newlist{thmenumerate}{enumerate}{1} % 'enumerate'-like list
\setlist[thmenumerate]{label=\upshape(\alph*)} % alphabetical numbering

\crefname{thmenumeratei}{part}{parts} % label for parts of enumerated list

% -------------

\begin{document}
\section{Real Analysis}

\addtocounter{theorem}{2} % just for this example

\noindent

(earlier stuff)

\begin{definition} 
Let $(X,\mathscr{M})$ be a measurable space. A function $f\colon X\to[-\infty,\infty]$ is said to be $\mathscr{M}$-measurable (or simply \emph{measurable} when the context is clear) if the preimage 
$f^{-1}((a,\infty])=\{x\in X\colon f(x)>a\}$ is measurable for every real number~$a$.
\end{definition}

\begin{example} \phantom{.}\par % force an immediate line break
\begin{thmenumerate}
\item Constant functions are measurable.
\item Given a subset $A$ of $X$, the characteristic function $\chi_{A}$ is a measurable function if and only if $A$ is measurable.
\item The continuous functions $f\colon \mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$ are \dots
\item The monotone functions $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ are \dots
\end{thmenumerate}
\end{example}

\begin{proposition} 
Let $(X,\mathscr{M})$ be a measurable space and let $f\colon X\to[-\infty,\infty]$ be a function. Then the following statements are equivalent:
\begin{thmenumerate}
\item For every real number $a$, the set \dots
\item For every real number $a$, the set \dots
\item For every real number $a$, the set \dots
\item For every real number $a$, the set \dots
\end{thmenumerate}
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition} 
Let $(X,\mathscr{M})$ be a measurable space. If $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions defined on $X$, then the sets
\begin{thmenumerate}
\item \label{part:greaterthan} $\{x\in X\colon f(x)>g(x)\}$,
\item \label{part:greaterthanorequal} $\{x\in X\colon f(x)\ge g(x)\}$, and 
\item \label{part:equal} $\{x\in X\colon f(x)=g(x)\}$
\end{thmenumerate}
are all measurable.
\end{proposition}

\begin{proof}
If $r_1,r_2,\dots$ is an enumeration of the rational numbers, then
\[
\{x\in X : f(x)>g(x)\} =
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigl[x\in X: f(x)>r_n\} \cap
\{x\in X: g(x)<r_n\}\bigr] 
\]
is measurable since it is a countable union of measurable sets, establishing \cref{part:greaterthan}.

\Cref{part:greaterthanorequal} follows by noting that
\[
\{x\in X: f(x)\ge g(x)\}=\{x\in X: g(x)>f(x)\}^c,
\]
is measurable by \ref{part:greaterthan}.

Finally, to show \cref{part:equal} observe that
\[
\{x\in X:f(x)=g(x)\}=\{x\in X: f(x)\ge g(x)\} \cap 
\{x\in X: g(x)\ge f(x)\}
\]
is measurable by \ref{part:greaterthanorequal}.
\end{proof}

\begin{remark}
We now want to show that \dots
\end{remark}

\noindent
(more stuff)

\section{Measure}

\begin{definition}
By a \emph{measure} $\mu$ on a measurable space $(X,\mathscr{M})$, we mean an extended real valued nonnegative set function $\mu\colon\mathscr{M}\to[0, \infty]$ for which $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ and which is \emph{countably additive} in the sense that for any countable disjoint collection $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of measurable sets,
\[
\mu\biggl(\,\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n \biggr) =
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_n)\,.
\]
By a \emph{measure space} $(X,\mathscr{M},\mu)$ we mean a measurable space $(X,\mathscr{M})$ together with a meausure~$\mu$ defined on~$\mathscr{M}$.
\end{definition}
\blindtext
\blindtext[4]
\section{Blind}
\blindtext[4]
\section{Help}
\blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Which font are you reffering to? Seems like it uses the default LaTeX font. The only different "font" is maybe for the title of the section where they use small caps, that you can enable with `\textsc{your text}`, or `\scshape your text`. In your case you can just add `\scshape` before the `\centering` to enable it for all sections. For the margins I don't think you can read them automatically from the pdf, but can can check the document properties in your reader to get the total paper size, and then measure the percentage of the margins using for instance GIMP or by using a simple ruler.

Comment: @Mico Thank you! Would you please help me, I am trying for along time but still have not figure out the solution of my questions.

Comment: Also your code for the margins seems quite complex. Usually the `geometry` package is used precisely to avoid setting them manually.

Comment: Ah, I also see some letters with a special font. They are called "calligraphic" font. You can write them with something like `\mathcal{M}` (the default mathcal font is a bit different and better looking in my opinion, not sure what they used exactly)

Comment: @tobiasBora Thank you, for mentioning about``\scshape``. Moreover, I have edited my question, to make the question (about fonts) more clear.

Comment: Your document has weird fonts, I guess you load a package that changes the font. Can you make a Minimal Working Example that compiles and shows the issue?

Comment: Notable, check that you do NOT have a line `\usepackage{times}` as it loads the Times New Roman font.

Comment: @tobiasBora Yes, I have not used this package. Please check edit.2.

Comment: You precisely do NOT want this package. Please read my comment about giving us a MWE. We can't help you otherwise.

Comment: @tobiasBora, I understood, (sorry in the beginning i did not understand the term MWE). Please have a look again at edit.2.

Comment: Welcome, @Afzal. // Usually the best strategy is to use the defaults and start writing. Use packages as you go, e.g. related to your math questions. Wrt layout there are plenty of support packages at ctan, which hide away most of the things in your preamble. E.g. have a look into the manual of class memoir, which tries to combine it all. If you just scan it, you’ll see what‘s possible. I also recommend using one of the books on Latex in parallel to get a feel for the defaults.

Comment: If you remove the `\usepackage{times}` you are back to the default font.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather than reinvent the wheel in terms of choosing the design elements of a document, I would employ a suitable document class that already defines many of the structural elements, such as the formatting of section headers, of the document of interest. For your particular document, one leading candidate would appear to be the `amsart` document class. The `amsart` document class also automatically loads the `amsmath`, `amssymb`, and `amsthm` packages.

And, do make good use of the capabilities of LaTeX packages such `geometry` (to set page and margin parameters), `enumitem` (for bespoke enumerate-like lists, say), and `cleveref` (for cross-referencing purposes).

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=3.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\hyphenation{pre-image} % avoid "preim-age"

\usepackage{cleveref} % for "clever" cross-references

%\usepackage{amsthm} % is loaded automatically by 'amsart' class
\theoremstyle{theorem} % italic lettering
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] 
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition} % all theorem-like environments to share the same counter

\theoremstyle{definition} % upright lettering
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark} % 'remark' env.: not numbered

\usepackage[scr=euler]{mathalpha} % for "Euler script"

\usepackage{enumitem} % for \newlist and \setlist macros
\newlist{thmenumerate}{enumerate}{1} % 'enumerate'-like list
\setlist[thmenumerate]{label=\upshape(\alph*)} % alphabetical numbering

\crefname{thmenumeratei}{part}{parts} % label for parts of enumerated list

% -------------

\begin{document}
\section{Real Analysis}
\addtocounter{theorem}{2} % just for this example

\noindent
(earlier stuff)

\begin{definition} 
Let $(X,\mathscr{M})$ be a measurable space. A function $f\colon X\to[-\infty,\infty]$ is said to be $\mathscr{M}$-measurable (or simply \emph{measurable} when the context is clear) if the preimage 
$f^{-1}((a,\infty])=\{x\in X\colon f(x)>a\}$ is measurable for every real number~$a$.
\end{definition}

\begin{example} \phantom{.}\par % force an immediate line break
\begin{thmenumerate}
\item Constant functions are measurable.
\item Given a subset $A$ of $X$, the characteristic function $\chi_{A}$ is a measurable function if and only if $A$ is measurable.
\item The continuous functions $f\colon \mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$ are \dots
\item The monotone functions $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ are \dots
\end{thmenumerate}
\end{example}

\begin{proposition} 
Let $(X,\mathscr{M})$ be a measurable space and let $f\colon X\to[-\infty,\infty]$ be a function. Then the following statements are equivalent:
\begin{thmenumerate}
\item For every real number $a$, the set \dots
\item For every real number $a$, the set \dots
\item For every real number $a$, the set \dots
\item For every real number $a$, the set \dots
\end{thmenumerate}
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition} 
Let $(X,\mathscr{M})$ be a measurable space. If $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions defined on $X$, then the sets
\begin{thmenumerate}
\item \label{part:greaterthan} $\{x\in X\colon f(x)>g(x)\}$,
\item \label{part:greaterthanorequal} $\{x\in X\colon f(x)\ge g(x)\}$, and 
\item \label{part:equal} $\{x\in X\colon f(x)=g(x)\}$
\end{thmenumerate}
are all measurable.
\end{proposition}

\begin{proof}
If $r_1,r_2,\dots$ is an enumeration of the rational numbers, then
\[
\{x\in X : f(x)>g(x)\} =
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigl[x\in X: f(x)>r_n\} \cap
\{x\in X: g(x)<r_n\}\bigr] 
\]
is measurable since it is a countable union of measurable sets, establishing \cref{part:greaterthan}.

\Cref{part:greaterthanorequal} follows by noting that
\[
\{x\in X: f(x)\ge g(x)\}=\{x\in X: g(x)>f(x)\}^c,
\]
is measurable by \ref{part:greaterthan}.

Finally, to show \cref{part:equal} observe that
\[
\{x\in X:f(x)=g(x)\}=\{x\in X: f(x)\ge g(x)\} \cap 
\{x\in X: g(x)\ge f(x)\}
\]
is measurable by \ref{part:greaterthanorequal}.
\end{proof}

\begin{remark}
We now want to show that \dots
\end{remark}

\noindent
(more stuff)

\section{Measure}

\begin{definition}
By a \emph{measure} $\mu$ on a measurable space $(X,\mathscr{M})$, we mean an extended real valued nonnegative set function $\mu\colon\mathscr{M}\to[0, \infty]$ for which $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ and which is \emph{countably additive} in the sense that for any countable disjoint collection $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of measurable sets,
\[
\mu\biggl(\,\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n \biggr) =
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_n)\,.
\]
By a \emph{measure space} $(X,\mathscr{M},\mu)$ we mean a measurable space $(X,\mathscr{M})$ together with a meausure~$\mu$ defined on~$\mathscr{M}$.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is really amazing, along with my needs, I learnt a lot from yous code. Thank you so much. By the way, could you please further guide me to put header (for document name; here REAL ANALYSIS and page numbering on the top), and top and bottom space size (that is can I further reduce it like in the pdf or maybe header can perform this)? However I tried to put header, using ``\usepakage{fancyhdr}`` but editor ignores the code.

Comment: @Afzal - You're most welcome. May I suggest that you post a *new query* -- which, of course, can build on the present query -- in which you would ask a specific question about how to set a running header in a document that uses the `amsart` document class?

Comment: @Mirco- Thank You! From your previous comment. I tried and finally I got what I wanted. Again thank you. Now, I am able to put the  document name on the header and also page numbers. I used couple of codes (Please see answer below). Moreover, I used pdf viewer and got the side of the above pdf that is 11.33 × 14.67 in (portrait). Could you please guide me, how can i issue this? My thought is to use ``\usepakage{a4paper,margin=3.75cm, 11.33 × 14.67 in (portrait)}[geometry]``.

Comment: Currently I have ``\usepackage[a4paper,margin=3.75cm, top=1.74cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=3.74cm,right=3.74cm]{geometry}``. It looks me better. If i change left and right margins a bit then textwidth is disturbed. (I don't wanna change textwidth)

Comment: @Afzal - I'm not familiar with the 11.33 × 14.67 in paper size. It would be gigantic yet also, oddly, somewhat smaller than the "A3" paper size (which is 11.7 x 16.5 in). What's wrong with the `a4paper` (or, if you prefer, `letterpaper`) paper size, which is part of your current setup?

Comment: Actually there was some gap from sides and top and bottom, I wanted to reduce that but I have done now. Finally I have find the appropriate size. But now again stuck in ``\maketitle`` and ``Date``. I am using your suggested codes but I am not able to write date (at the bottom), latex says use ``\maketitle`` command but whenever I use ``\maketitle`` I get error.

Comment: @Afzal - Sadly, but probably unsurprisingly, my mind-reading skills are worthless. If someone tells me that they're encountering an error without telling me what the error message says, I'm in no position to offer meaningful advice. Sorry.

Comment: No worries, you have literally helped me alot. Maybe without your help, I cannot figure things for along period of time. Moreover, surprisingly, I fixed the issue. Now all I have only single question! In ``amsart``, what should I do so corollaries followed by respective theorems get theorem number. For example ``theorem.1`` then ``corollary1.1.`` corollary``1.2.`` etc. In ``article`` class I use these commands : ``newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]`` and ``newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem}``.But sadly these are not working in amsart.

Comment: @Afzal - This has nothing to do with `amsart` vs. `article` document classes. The code I posted defines theorems, propositions, definitions, examples, etc all to be numbered with the current section number as a kind of prefix. Why? It's because that's what the screenshot you posted would appear to require. If this numbering system is, in fact, *not* what you want after all, you need to say so explicitly, and you need to state your preferred alternative specification for the numbering system.